# perl-regex in BSD grep as oppose to GNU grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep, homebrew

```
grep -Px -e '"[^|,"\v]*"(,"[^|,"\v]*")+\v' FILENAME.csv > FILENAME.csv
```

previously worked in `GNU Grep`, now because `-P` isn't in BSD Grep it no longer works.

which command could I use to get the same result?

Comment: Isn't `-E` good enough for this regex?

Comment: as oppose to using -Px altogether?

Comment: Please bear in mind that reading a file and at the same time redirecting to it (as in `grep ... FILE > FILE`) gives unpredictable results. It may or may not work. It often depends on the size of the file whether it is completely read before it gets (over)written. To be safe, redirect to another (temporary) file and move it afterwards (`grep ... FILE > FILE.new` and -- if the results are OK -- `mv FILE.new FILE`).

Comment: @ConnorPuleo No, just `-E` instead of `-P`, i.e. `grep -E -x -e '…'`. But I didn't try it.